# Unexpected output from function in Haskell

Tags: haskell, primes, type-signature

I have this function which takes an integer n, and returns the number of integers less than
n which are coprime with n. I don't know where my code might be failing as I think I check everything needed for it to work.

I expect an output like this:

```
eTotient 73 = 72
```

But I have one that  looks like this:

```
eTotient 73 = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72]
```

Here is my code:

```
divisorCoPrime :: Int -> [Maybe Int]
divisorCoPrime n = divisorCoPrime2 n n

divisorCoPrime2 :: Int -> Int -> [Maybe Int]
divisorCoPrime2 n 1 = []
divisorCoPrime2 n x
    | divides n x && isPrime x = Just x:divisorCoPrime2 n (x-1)
    | otherwise = divisorCoPrime2 n (x-1)

isCoprime :: Int -> Int -> Bool
isCoprime x y = isCoprime2 (divisorCoPrime x) (divisorCoPrime y)

isCoprime2 :: [Maybe Int] -> [Maybe Int] -> Bool
isCoprime2 [] y = True
isCoprime2 x [] = True
isCoprime2 (x:xs) y
    | foldl (||) False (map (x==) y) = False
    | otherwise = isCoprime2 xs y
    
eTotient :: Int -> [Int]
eTotient n = filter (isCoprime n ) [2..(n-1)]
```

Comment: `eTotient :: Int -> [Int]` says that `eTotient` returns a _list_ of integers (`[Int]`)

Comment: How can I make it return just an `Int` ?

Comment: You have a very interesting function named `isCoprime`. What does it do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function):

> Euler's totient function [which is what I'm guessing `eTotient` is supposed to be] counts the positive integers up to a given integer `n` that are relatively prime to `n`

`filter (isCoprime n ) [2..(n-1)]` is a *list* of such integers, but you want the *number* of these integers - the [*length*](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:length) of the list. Assuming the rest of the code is correct, that would look like this:

```
eTotient :: Int -> Int
eTotient n = length $ filter (isCoprime n ) [2..(n-1)]
```

Comment: For it to work as I want, I had to change the `2` for a `1`. Thanks a lot for the help!